# How to remove duplicate entries in ASP.Net MVC Index View table

Tags: c#, sql-server, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following scenario:

I have a `Contact` with properties `FirstName` and  `LastName`. A Contact can have multiple `PhoneNumbers` and as many `EmailAddresses`. I have identified these as 3 entities with common relationships. Please see the table definitions below:

```
create table Contact
(
    ID int primary key not null identity(1,1),
    FirstName nvarchar(40),
    LastName nvarchar(40)
);
go

create table ContactNumber
(
    ID int primary key not null identity(1,1),
    PhoneNumber nvarchar(40)
);
go

create table EmailAddress
(
    ID int primary key not null identity(1,1),
    EmailAddress nvarchar(40)
);
go

create table UserContact
(
    ID int primary key not null identity(1,1),
    ContactID int foreign key references Contact(ID),
    ContactNumberID int foreign key references ContactNumber(ID),
    EmailID int foreign key references EmailAddress(ID)
);
go
```

Now I need to display these users in a Web Application of my choice. I chose C# MVC with a Razor Engine for the View. I'm battling to model this view in a table. The table needs Action Links to edit, delete, create a new contact and view the details of the contact. I want the result set to show as below:

```
FirstName | LastName | ContactNumber | EmailAddress
-------------------------------------------------------
James     | Smith    | 082 111 5454  | james@domain1.com | edit | details | delete
                                     | james@domain2.com
                                     | james@domain3.com
--------------------------------------------------------
Luther    | Arnolds  | 082 111 5455  | luther@domain1.com | edit | details | delete
                     | 082 111 5456  |
--------------------------------------------------------
Sarah     | Jones    | 082 111 5510  |  sarah@domain.com  | edit | details | delete
---------------------------------------------------------
          |          |               |
```

However I'm just not finding the write way to translate the `ContactNumberID` and `EmailID` columns from `UserContact` to map from their corresponding bridging tables. The issue that I am facing right now is that it is duplicating the records in `UserContact` thus making the table contain a lot of redundant data. For example the record for `James Smith` would be repeated 3 times. How can I achieve this in ASP.Net MVC without any duplication of entries?

Comment: Can a single email address or phone number be used by more than 1 contact? I suspect not. I would put ContactID as foreign key in the EmailAddress and PhoneNumber tables and drop the UserContact table. You don't have a many to many here. You have two distinct 1 to many relationships.

Comment: @SeanLange Okay, then how will I map the relationship to `Contact`? Because it's refusing for me to add a composite primary key referencing `ContactID` on `EmailAddress` and `ContactNumber` tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this. Notice that I changed up the column names a little bit. It is a pet peeve of mine to have a column named ID. It is a ContactID (or whatever) regardless of which table it is in. I also really dislike column names changing for the same piece of data in related tables.

```
create table Contact
(
    ContactID int primary key not null identity(1,1),
    FirstName nvarchar(40) not null,
    LastName nvarchar(40) not null
);
go

create table ContactNumber
(
    ContactNumberID int primary key not null identity(1,1),
    PhoneNumber nvarchar(40) not null,
    ContactID int not null,
    constraint FK_ContactNumber_Contact_ContactID Foreign Key (ContactID) references Contact(ContactID)
);
go

create table EmailAddress
(
    EmailAddressID int primary key not null identity(1,1),
    EmailAddress nvarchar(40) not null,
    ContactID int not null,
    constraint FK_EmailAddress_Contact_ContactID Foreign Key (ContactID) references Contact(ContactID)
);
go
```